# End Loop when significant value found : Stata?

Tags: loops, matrix, stata

could you help me in figuring out: ho do i tell Stata to end the loop over iterations when it finds the first positive and significant value of a particular coefficient in a regression.

Here is a small sample using publicly available dataset that shows what I am trying to do: In the following case, I want stata to stop looping when it finds the "year" coefficient to be positive and significant.

```
set more off
clear all
clear matrix
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/abdata
forvalues i=1/8{
xtabond n w k ys year, lags(`i') noconstant
matrix b = e(b)'
mat byear = b["year",1]
if `i'==1  matrix byear=b["year",1]
else matrix byear=(byear\ b["year",1])
}
```

Could you  please help in figuring out how to tell stata to stop looping when it finds a condition is met.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that seems to do what you want. I had to set the confidence level to 80 (from the default of 95) so it would terminate before it exceeded the maximum number of lags.

```
set more off
clear all
clear matrix
set level 80
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/abdata
forvalues i=1/8{
quietly xtabond n w k ys year, lags(`i') noconstant
matrix t = r(table)
scalar b = t[rownumb(t,"b"),colnumb(t,"year")]
scalar p = t[rownumb(t,"pvalue"),colnumb(t,"year")]
scalar r = 1-r(level)/100
scalar q = (b>0) & (p<=r)
if q {
    display "success with `i' lags"
    display "b: " b " p: " p " r: " r " q: " q
    xtabond
    continue, break
    }
else {
    display "no luck with `i' lags"
    }
}
```

which yields

```
no luck with 1 lags
success with 2 lags
b: .00759529 p: .18035747 r: .2 q: 1

Arellano-Bond dynamic panel-data estimation     Number of obs     =        611
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =        140
Time variable: year
                                                Obs per group:
                                                              min =          4
                                                              avg =   4.364286
                                                              max =          6

Number of instruments =     31                  Wald chi2(6)      =    1819.55
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
One-step results
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           n |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [80% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           n |
         L1. |   .3244849   .0774312     4.19   0.000     .1727225    .4762474
         L2. |  -.0266879   .0363611    -0.73   0.463    -.0979544    .0445785
             |
           w |  -.5464779   .0562155    -9.72   0.000    -.6566582   -.4362975
           k |    .360622   .0330634    10.91   0.000     .2958189    .4254252
          ys |   .5948084   .0818672     7.27   0.000     .4343516    .7552652
        year |   .0075953   .0056696     1.34   0.180    -.0035169    .0187075
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instruments for differenced equation
        GMM-type: L(2/.).n
        Standard: D.w D.k D.ys D.year

. 
end of do-file
```

Comment: Thank you so much @WilliamLisowski . This helps a lot. I have learnt something new.

Comment: My initial attempt had a coding error, which when resolved led to the need to `set limit`. With those two changes, which were reflected in the code I posted, the loop again ended with 2 lags, and I did did not replace the output, thinking it unchanged. Wrong! I have made the needed changes to the output, which is why the post was edited after the answer was accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yeah I had noticed that so instead in my code I put a specific value of 0.100 in "p<=r".